# document.getElementsByClassName subgroup

Tags: xcode, cocoa

I want to get the value of a table cell. but when I choose the class, I get all values of the row. How can I specify may selection? My code since now:
 `[myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByClassName('class_Name')[0].innerText;"];`

My Idea was to make it like this but it does not work:

`[waerungskurse stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByClassName('charts_table_content')[0].[2].innerText;"];`
The Number is the column I want to select.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName('class')[0].getElementsByClassName('subClass')[0].innerText;`